# UIButton Constraint Failure, but works with UILabel

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uibutton, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to add a button pragmatically to a UIView. This code will work with a UI label, but when using it with a button, the constraints fail. How can I make this work? Thanks.

```
let homeButton =  UIButton(frame: CGRectZero)
    homeButton.setTitle("Home", forState: .Normal)
    homeButton.titleLabel!.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
    homeButton.titleLabel!.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    homeButton.titleLabel!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    containerView.addSubview(homeButton)

    let buttonWidthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: homeButton, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.containerView, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 0.5, constant: 0)
    containerView.addConstraint(buttonWidthConstraint)
    let buttonHeightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: homeButton, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.containerView, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 0.5,constant: 0)
    containerView.addConstraint(buttonHeightConstraint)

    let buttonXConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: homeButton, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.containerView, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    let buttonYConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: homeButton, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.containerView, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0)
    containerView.addConstraint(buttonXConstraint)
    containerView.addConstraint(buttonYConstraint)
```

Comment: use `homeButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

Comment: That works. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use `homeButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` instead of `homeButton.titleLabel!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`.

because you should disable autoresizingmask for `button` not for button's `titleLabel`!!!

Hope this will help :)